# ¿Cómo hacer para que no cualquiera pueda hacer peticiones HTTP?

Tags: java, android-studio, webservice, eclipse, http

Tengo una pequeña aplicación móvil en android studio y un web services en eclipse. El usuario puede hacer peticiones GET y POST desde la aplicación móvil pero, esas mismas peticiones las puedo hacer a través de una navegador web o de Postman.
Quisiera tener seguridad en las peticiones para que solo se puedan realizar a través de la aplicación móvil.

**¿Cómo podría lograr esto?**

Nota: Tanto la aplicación como el web services los desarrolle en crudo, no utilice ningún framework. El web services lo tengo alojado en tomcat.

Apenas inicio con el tema de seguridad, espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

**EDICIÓN.**
Agrego el código que utilizo para realizar la petición.

Web Services

```
//ListProduct

public class ListProduct extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ListProductImpl imp = new ListProductImpl();
        ArrayList<ProductoBeam> alstd = imp.getData();
        
        if (alstd != null) {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(alstd);
            PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
            pw.write(array.toString());
            pw.print(array.toString());
        }
    }
}


//ListProductImpl
public class ListProductImpl {
    String DRIVER="";
    String URL="";
    String USER="";
    String PASS="";
    
    String SQL="select * from datos.producto";
    
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    
    ArrayList<ProductoBeam> alStd = new ArrayList<ProductoBeam>();

    public ArrayList<ProductoBeam> getData() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                ProductoBeam p = new ProductoBeam();
                p.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                p.setDescripcion(rs.getString("descripcion"));
                p.setPrecio(rs.getString("precio"));
                p.setImagen(rs.getString("imagen"));
                alStd.add(p);
                System.out.print("Datos agregados correctamente al array");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ListProductImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ListProductImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return alStd;
    }
}
```

Android Studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerProductos;

    List<Product> productList;

    private static final String URL_product = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        recyclerProductos = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerProductos);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerProductos.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerProductos.setHasFixedSize(true);

        productList = new ArrayList<>();

        loadProduct();
    }
}

public void loadProduct() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_product, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        productList.add(new Product(
                                product.getString("nombre"),
                                product.getString("descripcion"),
                                product.getString("imagen")
                        ));
                    }
                    ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                    recyclerProductos.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", error.toString());
                    }
                });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Autenticando las peticiones.

Comment: Gracias por respondes @Alfabravo ¿tendrás algún ejemplo o una documentación para leer y darme una idea de como hacerlo.

Comment: Hay muchas opciones y esa no es la idea del sitio. Busca cómo asegurar web services en el stack que lo tengas definido (no lo sabemos) y ahí verás cómo implementarlo.

Comment: Agrega como realizas la petición actualmente, esto para dar una opción, recuerda que debes agregar lo que trataste de preferencia, saludos.

Comment: Hola Jorgesys♦ ya he actualizado la pregunta. Gracias :) Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El administrador del servidor debe restringir tus peticiones a la cual realizarías la petición, debe configurar que [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) solo es permitido para realizar la misma.

En el caso de tu app debes definir el [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) permitido para que las apps puedan realizar peticiones por ejemplo si el administrador define que es "Android/kayvosapp/1.1", configura este valor para realizar tu petición.

```
public static String makeServiceCall(final String postUrl, final Map<String, String> postParams) {

    StringBuilder responseBuilder  = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        final URL mUrl = new URL(postUrl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");

        //*Define User-Agent para realizar petición.
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android/kayvosapp/1.1");

        conn.connect();
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        final OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(postParams));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        final int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                responseBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            responseBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseBuilder.append(e.getMessage());
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseBuilder.append(e.getMessage());
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    } finally {
        if (null != conn) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return responseBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hola Jorgesys♦ hasta ahora pude contestar e implementarlo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió de mucho para guiarme y funciono muy bien. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente @kayvos, saludos!